# How to get unique category data from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object like this:

```
data.bills = [
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '220', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' },
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '20', category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16' },
    { date: '2018-02-20', amount: '120', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' }
]
```

Now i want to create a new array from this like this(Req Output):

```
data.allUniqueCategories = [
    {category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48'},
    { category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16'}
]
```

I tried something like this but its becoming too complex can anyone tell the simple solution thanks..

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) { 
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) { 
        for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[i]; } 
        return arr2; 
        } else {
    return Array.from(arr); } 
}

c.data.categories = [].concat(_toConsumableArray(new Set(data.bills.map(function (bill) {
    return bill.state;
}))));

console.log(c.data.categories);
//['Electricity','Gas']
```

but i want in this format

```
//[{category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48'},{ category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16'}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#reduce()` to create an object with the categories as keys and get the values of that object as result

```js
const bills = [
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '220', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' },
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '20', category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16' },
    { date: '2018-02-20', amount: '120', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' }
]

const res = Object.values(bills.reduce((a,{category,categoryId})=>{
   a[category]={category, categoryId}
   return a;
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.bills = [
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '220', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' },
    { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '20', category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16' },
    { date: '2018-02-20', amount: '120', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' }
]
data.allUniqueCategories = [...new Set(data.bills.map(o => o.category));
```

Here `map` is getting categories and adding to the new `Set`, Set can contain only unique values, so if there will be duplicate categories, it will not be added in `Set`, after finishing `map` it will spread `Set` values into new array by this operator `...`

Answer (score 1):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `bills` into an object with the category as the key, and than convert to array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const bills = [{"date":"2018-01-20","amount":"220","category":"Electricity","categoryId":"48"},{"date":"2018-01-20","amount":"20","category":"Gas","categoryId":"16"},{"date":"2018-02-20","amount":"120","category":"Electricity","categoryId":"48"}]

const allUniqueCategories = Object.values(bills.reduce((r, { category, categoryId }) => {
  r[category] = { category, categoryId };

  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(allUniqueCategories);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` method with `Map` as accumulator param to create unique array by `category` and `categoryId` props.

```js
const bills = [
  { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '220', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' },
  { date: '2018-01-20', amount: '20', category: 'Gas' ,categoryId: '16' },
  { date: '2018-02-20', amount: '120', category: 'Electricity' ,categoryId: '48' }
]

const uniq = bills.reduce((r, {category, categoryId}) => {
  let key = `${category}|${categoryId}`;
  r.set(key, (r.get(key) || {category, categoryId}));
  return r;
}, new Map())

console.log([...uniq.values()])
```